# consultation about transfer Variables from dialog to activity

Tags: android

i need to pass varible value from dialog to activity

my dialog looks like this:

```
public class dataa extends Dialog {
    public dataa(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    EditText txtPASS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.data);
        setTitle("                TEST                 ");
        Button btnOK;
        Button btnexit;
        txtName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtName.setText("TEST");
        txtPASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new Close());
        btnexit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnexit.setOnClickListener(new exit());
    }

    private class Close implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyParam.TmpPass = txtPASS.getText().toString().trim(); --> this the value i need to use in my activity
            dataa.this.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private class exit implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyParam.TmpPass = txtPASS.getText().toString().trim(); --> this the value i need to use in my activity
             dataa.this.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

i transfer the value of `EditText txtPASS` to `MyParam.TmpPass` that in my class

by pressing button i open the dialog and need to do something with the val

my activity looks like this:

```
 public void Delete_Record()
     {
         final dataa myDialog = new dataa(context);
         myDialog.show();

         Button btnOK=(Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
         btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (MyParam.TmpPass.equals(MyParam.SYSPASS))  <-- i cant get the value of MyParam.TmpPass from the dialog 
                    {
                        //if the password good make some thing
                        myDialog.cancel();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
           });

        Button btnExit=(Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myDialog.cancel();
               }
           });
     }
```

Comment: You need to actually ask a question :)

Comment: Assuming your `MyParam.SYSPASS` is hardcoded/predefined, what is the meaning of *cant get the value*, are you getting **NULL** or garbage or is it crashing?..did you check the log, post the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on wrong path currently. Interface is the best way to achieve this.

I have edited your code try this and let me know.

**dataa.java**

```
public class dataa extends Dialog {
    public dataa(Context context,MyDialogListener myDialogListener) {
        super(context);
        this.myDialogListener=myDialogListener;
    }

    MyDialogListener myDialogListener;
    EditText txtPASS;


    public interface MyDialogListener{
        void onOk(dataa dialog,String pass);
        void onExit(dataa dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.data);
        setTitle("                TEST                 ");
        Button btnOK;
        Button btnexit;
        txtName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtName.setText("TEST");
        txtPASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new Close());
        btnexit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnexit.setOnClickListener(new exit());
    }

    private class Close implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //MyParam.TmpPass = txtPASS.getText().toString().trim(); --> this the value i need to use in my activity
            //dataa.this.dismiss();
            myDialogListener.onOk(dataa.this,txtPASS.getText().toString().trim());

        }
    }

    private class exit implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //MyParam.TmpPass = txtPASS.getText().toString().trim(); --> this the value i need to use in my activity
             myDialogListener.onExit(dataa.this);
             dataa.this.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**How to access from activity?**

```
public void Delete_Record()
    {
        final dataa myDialog = new dataa(this,new dataa.MyDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOk(dataa dialog, String pass) {

                if (pass.equals(MyParam.SYSPASS))
                {
                    //if the password good make some thing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onExit(dataa dialog) {

            }
        });
        myDialog.show();

    }
```